# Count values across multiple columns with grouping variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains data that looks like this:

```
levels char_1 char_2
a      dog    dog
a      cat    dog
b      cow    cat
b      dog    dog
```

I'd like to `group_by` the `levels` column and compute the total number of times that a value appears either in the `char_1` column or `char_2` column

The resulting dataframe would look like:

```
levels char  count
a      dog    3
a      cat    1
b      dog    2
b      cow    1
b      cat    1
```

I've experimented with pivot tables, but can't wrap my head around pandas syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot and then [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counts:

```
df1 = (df.melt('levels', value_name='char')
         .groupby(['levels','char'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
  levels char  count
0      a  cat      1
1      a  dog      3
2      b  cat      1
3      b  cow      1
4      b  dog      2
```

Comment: Shockingly fast answer.  Of course!  The answer is always melt.  Thank you.